# patch not creating new files

Tags: bash, patch

I'm learning how to use `patch`, and have encountered strange behaviour when patching two directories:

- `original_directory` contains one file (`file1`) containing three lines.
- `updated_directory` contains two files: `file1` with two extra lines, and an additional `file2` (containing seven lines).

I issued `diff -Nur original_directory/ updated_directory/ > original_directory.patch`. However, when I perform the patch (`patch -p0 < original_directory.patch`), I get the following output:

```
patching file updated_directory/file1
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file updated_directory/file1.rej
The next patch would create the file updated_directory/file2,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] n
Apply anyway? [n] n
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

However, when I issue `cd original_directory/; patch -p1 < ../original_directory.patch` everything works just fine!

I'm sure that `patch -p0 < original_directory.patch` worked just the other day...

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is expected and usual. You patch file probably looks something like:

```
diff -Nur original_directory/file1 updated_directory/file1
--- original_directory/file1    2018-09-26 15:00:33.929223318 +0900
+++ updated_directory/file2 2018-09-26 15:00:41.555279201 +0900
...
...
diff -Nur original_directory/file2 updated_directory/file2
--- original_directory/file2    1970-01-01 09:00:00.000000000 +0900
+++ updated_directory/file2 2018-09-26 15:00:49.325037178 +0900
...
...
```

With `-p1`, the first component of the paths of changed files are removed, so the `patch` sees instructions to make changes to `file2` and `file1` in the current directory.

With `-p0`, no path components are removed from the paths, so `patch` sees instructions to make changes to `updated_directory/file2` and `updated_directory/file1`, but those files already have the required changes.

Comment: Hi muru. I appreciate you explaining that for me :) With that in mind, I'm curious when the '-p0' option would be necessary?

Comment: @R.Neville it depends on how the patch file was created. If you do `git diff`, you'll see something like `a/file1 b/file1` (so you have to use `-p1` to remove the `b/`), but with `cvs diff` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26504/70524), it's just `file1`, so you cannot remove any path components there.

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks again!